# Automatic adding songs with album

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a music library based on Django. So, I have basic models for song, album in 'shop' app and copy models for user's collection. I wonder, is there any way to add songs related to an album when user's creating the copy of some album?

Basic models for shop app:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=timezone.now().year)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=cover_album_directory_path)

    is_single = models.BooleanField()
    is_ep = models.BooleanField()
    is_compilation = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    related_album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    album_position = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    lyrics = models.TextField(blank=True)
    track = models.FileField(upload_to=song_directory_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Models for copies of albums and songs:

```
class CopyAlbum(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Library)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album.name

class CopySong(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Library)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song.name
```

What I really need: After I created a copy album, Django must automatically save copysongs related to album.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can add this functionality to the method where you actualy create a copy of the album; but why do you want to copy songs? You already have access to all songs through `copy_album.album.song_set`.

Comment: @Selcuk, what about deleting some songs from album? Will it delete songs from original album, when I delete songs through the copy of album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use signals.

In the CopyAlbum, CopySong models file:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save,post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save,sender=CopyAlbum)
def copy_songs(*args,**kwargs):

 copy_album_instance = kwargs['instance']
 ... copy the songs ...

@receiver(post_delete,sender=CopyAlbum)
def delete_songs(*args,**kwargs):

 copy_album_instance = kwargs['instance'] ## deleted, an instance w/o db record
 ... delete the songs ...
```